# BouncyCastle CMSSignedData from external signature and public key certificate

Tags: java, pdfbox, bouncycastle

I have an X509Certificate, and a byte array that represents a raw signature created by a remote server (which has my private key). 
I'm trying to add this signature with PDFBox 2.0.18. For that, I need CMSSignedData object.
How do I generate CmsSignedData without private key (only signature, public key, certificate)?

Comment: You usually need to start creating the CMS signed data object before requesting the signature bytes. Every decent profile requires the use of ESSCerrId signed attributes...

Comment: You can contruct the underlying DER "manually" by using the BC ASN1Primitive derivations. At least you need to have the signed message itself and knowledge about the used signing algorithm.

Comment: I posted an update. Please, check out..

Comment: What exactly is the `content` you sign?

Comment: Pleased share an example pdf signed by your code.

Comment: `ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning =
                    document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
            byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());
            externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);`

Comment: Here you can find the file we.tl/t-RQIPbfMHDA

Comment: The certificate chain is incomplete. It should contain all certificates up to and including the root certificate. Please check how many certificates are in "certificateChain".

Comment: (If you want a response by somebody, use "@" so this person will get a mail some time later and/or an alert in the browser when on an SO page)