# Sign a Pdf document using AWS KMS

Tags: spring, amazon-kms, aws-sdk-java

I have created in AWS KMS Console a Asymmetric key, RSA_2048, for Sign and verify.
I have created an IAM user to use this key and attached to it the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Sign",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

now in my java code im using the following method:

```
    public byte[] signPDFWithAWS(ByteArrayOutputStream pdf) {
        try {
            // user creadentials
            AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(Config.accesskey, Config.secretkey));
            AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).withRegion(Config.region).build();
            String keyId = "MY-KEY-ID";

            byte[] pdfBytes = pdf.toByteArray();
            SignRequest signRequest = new SignRequest()
                    .withKeyId(keyId)
                    .withMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(pdfBytes));

            SignResult signResult = kmsClient.sign(signRequest);

            return signResult.getSignature().array();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.fatal("Fatalerror: ", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and when it gets to the kmsClient.sign(signRequest) part - it throws an exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe
```

what am I doing wrong?

How can I programmatically sign a pdf file so that it WONT show "Signature validity is unknown" in Adobe Reader app?

1. read documentation
2. read [Sign a PdfDocument using the digital signature returned by AWS KMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867778/sign-a-pdfdocument-using-the-digital-signature-returned-by-aws-kms) answers but didnt understood.